# How to make dired "collapse" empty directories?

Tags: dired

I [prefer flatter projects](http://this-plt-life.tumblr.com/post/36425231672/when-a-code-base-uses-a-directory-structure-deeper).

Unfortunately some languages dictate a deeper structure. When dealing with those, it helps (a little) if directory views "collapse" empty paths. [Example how GitHub does this](https://github.com/plumatic/schema/tree/master/src).

I'm wondering how I could make `dired` do this?

- Is there an existing option I'm overlooking?
- Is there an existing package that adds this?
- Should I attempt to write such a package? O_o

---

*Update*: Drew commented that the GitHub example isn't clear and asked me to explain. Their [August 19, 2014 blog post](https://github.com/blog/1877-folder-jumping) explains a new feature they call "Folder Jumping".

Comment: You could suggest such a feature on @Fuco's https://github.com/Fuco1/dired-hacks...

Comment: The question is not very clear, to me at least. What does it mean to "collapse" an empty directory in its parent Dired listing? Subdirs are already collapsed, in the sense that their contents are not shown by default. You can of course insert any subdir, using `i`, but that "expands" it, instead of collapsing. Please clarify what you are looking for versus what you see in vanilla Dired. Give an example. (Your GitHub "example" is not clear to me. Show what you would like for a Dired listing.)

Comment: There is a new "dired-collapse" package on melpa for this.

Answer (score 1):

I think I should self-answer. (But it's not an exact answer to my question as-asked. So I'm not sure if I should self-accept.)

Thanks to wasamasa I checked out `dired-subtree`. Unlike plain `dired`, it inserts subdir trees "inline". Nice.

Next I realized I can use its `dired-subtree-cycle` command with a prefix argument to expand N levels deep. So I bound that to <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

```el
(use-package dired-subtree
  :ensure t
  :init (setq dired-subtree-use-backgrounds nil)
  :config (bind-keys :map dired-mode-map
                     ;; With C-u prefix expands N deep.
                     ;; C-u TAB will expand 4
                     ;; C-u C-u TAB will expand 16
                     ;; C-u C-u C-u TAB will expand 64
                     ("TAB" . dired-subtree-cycle)))
```

As a result, I can <kbd>C-u C-u TAB</kbd> to expand 16 levels deep.

I can even <kbd>C-u C-u C-u TAB</kbd> to expand 64 levels -- enough for even the most ceremonial languages (hello, Java).

Another <kbd>TAB</kbd> closes the whole subtree.

Although not the GitHub-style "folder jumping" I originally imagined, I think this will work as well or better, for me.

Comment: Well, you can still open a ticket on that repository, even if it's just for exchanging ideas with someone knowing their way around dired, perhaps that will give you a hint how to do even better.